# jQuery lazyload stops loading when another javascript is fired

Tags: jquery, jquery-lazyload

i know it is really hard to give an answer without much of my source codes, but I would like to know if anyone ran into this problem before. This is my lazy load codes.

```
function displayLogo(merchant,merchantLogoId){
 $.getJSON("http://202.161.46.8:83/TGLWebService/logows/getBigLogo/"+merchant, function(data) {
      document.getElementById(merchantLogoId).innerHTML = ("<img class='lazy' src='img/icon/ImageLoading.jpg' data-original="+data.bigImageUrl+">");
      $('img.lazy').lazyload();
  }); 
}
```

It works fine when I run my website and scroll up and down and lazyloading works perfectly.

The problem occurs lets say when initially i launch the website and the first few images are loaded even if i scroll down, but if I lets say open my navigation menu, my lazyloading stops working when i scroll up and down, i.e. it doesnt load the rest of the images which are not loaded.

I tried using $('img.lazy').lazyload(); inside document.ready and moving out of the displaylogo function but it does not work at all, i.e. when the page loads, lazyloading does not work at all.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can confirm that it is a JS issue by adding a button that trigger an ajax call or something (maybe an 'alert' could be enough) and check if it does stop your lazy loading to work. this is a good starting point.

Comment: i tried an alert and it doesnt seem to affect it, on more testing, I realize that if i open a popup etc, it will have the same effect.

Comment: Same effect ? It stops the lazy loading ? Have you tried with modal and non-modal dialogs ? (I assume that you mean dialog when you say popup). I can't give you more clues at the moment, sorry.

Comment: URL of the page you have problems with?

Answer (score 0):

try add a .complete(); to the getJSON

for example

```
    $.getJSON('include/controllers/getCats.php', function(data) {
    jsonObj = data;
}).complete(function(){
       $('img.lazy').lazyload();

});
```